# Entity Framework 4 and Emergency systems

Tags: nhibernate, orm, frameworks, entity

I'm considering using an ORM like Entity Framework 4 for a system like 911. Can someone please enumerate the pros and cons for such systems?
Thanks in advance! Daniel

Comment: NHibernate's been around longer.

Answer (score 1):

Not to promote my own product but I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18132/ado-net-entity-vs-nhibernate) some time ago. Do a search on StackOverflow and there's a lot about different ORMs being compared.

After all this time I've come to the conclusion that you should pick one that seems flexible and learn it really well.

Comment: I understand it, but my point of view is about performance for a system which should receive lots of entries per day and should retrieve the information in a good time, but it's not a real time system.

Comment: When I alluded to a flexible option, I meant one that could be optimized for performance or alternately optimized for flexibility. Your application architecture will be critical in this, it's less likely to hinge on whether you picked NHibernate versus Entity Framework.